# ob_end_clean not clear buffer after include

Tags: php, include, hook, redeclare

I am using this code to get module info in my CMS:

```
global $hook;
$hook = new bn_hookfunc;

ob_start();
include_once($mydir);
ob_end_clean();
$mod_name = $hook->call_function('module_name');
$mod_ver  = $hook->call_function('module_version');
```

And my module config.php looks like this:

```
global $hook;
$hook->module_name='modname';
$hook->module_version='modver';

function modname()
{
    return 'test module';
}

function modver()
{
    return 'v1.0.0';
}
```

This code works perfectly in PHP 5.4.

But I updated my xampp to 1.83, and so PHP was updated to 5.5.3, and now i have this error:

```
Cannot redeclare modname() (previously declared in \modules\example\config.php:13) in \modules\Z48ilWd2l80cYed8\config.php on line 14
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: You've probably got an `include()` or `require()` somewhere instead of an `include_once()`/`require_once()`, causing the config.php to be loaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad architecture. I don't understand how it works in last version. If each of modules has function `modname` and `modver` it's error must have, because in php you can't declare several function with the same name. In your case, I think that you, for example, first includes file `\modules\example\config.php` and than `\modules\Z48ilWd2l80cYed8\config.php`. Check it please and remove including `\modules\example\config.php`

Comment: i use this code<code>ob_start();
include_once($mydir);
ob_end_clean();<code>for load each config.php in buffer and then clear buffer for prevent redeclare functions but it not work now

Comment: @lord_viper you don't find including `\modules\example\config.php`?

Comment: i found this and include perfect but ob_end_clean not work to clear buffer this code work perfet for my cms gadget